# delete items that are checked without $_POST php

Tags: php, session, post, checkbox

I've stuck with the following issue:
I have a table with texts and each one has a checkbox next to it. I also have a button-like link "Delete selected". What I want is to give the ability to the user to select many texts through checkboxes and delete the selected all together. The problem is tha I don't want to use a form so I can't use $_POST so I suppose I have to use $_SESSION. I have used sessions before but I don't know how to combine them with checkboxes..

if you could give me some tips or examples I would be very gratefull..

parts of my code to give you a clue..

view_texts.php

```
<?php 

        $sql="SELECT * FROM texts";
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $i=1;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
     ?>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo substr($row['description'],0,20); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['page_id']; ?></td>

            <td><a href="edit_text.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><img src="images/user_edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" />                   </a></td>
            <td><a href="delete_text.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="ask"><img src="images/trash.png" alt="" 
            title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
       $i++;
            }
      ?> 
<a href="delete_selected_texts.php" class="bt_red"><span class="bt_red_lft"></span><strong>Διαγραφή επιλεγμένων</strong><span class="bt_red_r"></span></a>
```

delete_selected_texts.php

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['check']))
        {
            foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value)
                {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM texts WHERE id =".$value;
                    mysql_query ($sql);

                }

        }  
?>
```

this is the code that i use for textboxes inside a form tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to use a form, so I can't use POST"?

Comment: How can you not use a form?  The only way you can get the information from the client to the server is with a request (`POST` is your simplest bet, and the most compliant).

Comment: The `$_SESSION` superglobal saves state on the server. It cannot accomplish data transference between a client and a server. That's what POST (and GET) are for.

Comment: I read that if you don't use a form you can't actually post something..is this wrong?? it's a little complicated why I don't want to use form to that particular page..for example I don't want to post all the form through action="" but only the part with checkboxes through the link for selected items that I have.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck on not using a form, for whatever reason, you're looking at using javascript and sending an AJAX request on the POST instead. I'd recommend using jQuery, as that greatly simplifies the process of selecting the elements you want to target.

It would look something like this...

```
$(document).function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(e){
              var deleteItem = $("input:id").val();
              $.ajax({
                      type: "POST";
                      data: deleteItem;
                      url: "path/to/a/file.php";
                      success: function(data){
                              if (data="success"){
                                  $(this).css("backgroundcolor", "blue");
                              } else {
                                  alert("failed to find item");
                              }
                          }
          });
}
```

You would need then to have a file that the Ajax request sends the data to that will build a list of items to delete/take items off that list, which will be stored and called up when the delete_selected_texts.php is called up to be deleted.

NB.: The jQuery above hasn't been checked. There's an excellent chance of there being several errors in there.

Comment: thank you for your answer!is there a way not to use javascript??because i do not have much knowledge of this and of ajax either..

Comment: @fotant: you should learn it then. That's the joy of programming, you will never know *everything*, there's always something new to learn!

Comment: @knittl I would like to know if I have an alternative that could be easier for me to use. Sometimes there are more than one solution for the same problem...

Comment: A Form is about the only other option AFAIK. If you go with a Form and Submit button, have the page reloaded and some logic to check to see if the POST has the submit value. If so, execute the delete_selected_texts.php logic instead and redirect to the page of your choice with a header command.